# Anchoring with many TextBox controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a science fair project and I really need to move forward beyond anchors. I have worked for a couple of days on anchoring this window and I cannot figure out how to resize all of these well.

Can somebody label this image with anchors and explain exactly how they work in a way that will make sense to a 12 year old?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if we can label anything, because we have no idea how your anchors are set up. Your window (at least the left side) looks like it could use a `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: There are too many controls and too many flavors. But an anchor to a particular side of the window means that the distance of the control(equivalent side) to that side remains constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have marked the necessary `Anchors` in colors

You will need a little code in addition to the anchors, since `Anchors` can't handle more than one  control in relation to the borders of its parent. In your layout you have three groupBoxes all (presumably) sharing the center of the form.. You could calculate `dist` if you want to, too..

[image: labeled layout]

Here is a piece of code to get you started with the GroupBoxes:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int dist = 3;  // set to the distance between the GroupBoxes!
    int width = (oneWideTextBox.Width - dist * 2) / 3;
    groupBox1.Width = width ;
    groupBox2.Left = groupBox1.Right + dist;
    groupBox2.Width = groupBox1.Width;
    groupBox3.Left = groupBox2.Right + dist;
    groupBox3.Width = groupBox1.Width;
}
```

Of course I have made some assumptions about how you want it to work.. I hope you can take it from here! Feel free to ask!!